Ubuntu 24.04 fingerprint issue
I am using ubuntu 24.04 on VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X515EA_X51, 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7
I am facing an issue which I have also faced with the previous ubuntu distros,
my system is not recognising the fingerprint reader, it is working perfectly on windows but if I try to enroll my fingerprint it first asks me about the finger I want and then asks me the password, after entering the password it shows me that "failed to enroll fingerprint".
lsusb is showing this devices
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 3938:1031 MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 322e:2103 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3557 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
kindly pls help me with it
